# Export last months git commits

Tags: git

is there any command in Git to export all files and the folder structure from e.g. the last Month or the last 7 days ?

I am looking for something like this(just over a period of time):

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $commit_id | xargs tar -rf mytarfile.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can back up individual commits all in one go using `git format-patch`. But you will still need the original repo to re-apply the patch to.

```
commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 --before="1 month ago" origin/master)
datestr=$(date +%F)
git format-patch --stdout $commit.. | gzip -c > /path/to/backups/backup.$datestr.am.gz
```

Comment: This is very good. You can also use `--since` instead of `--before` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**git bundle**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html). This is mainly good for moving files to another machine (possible offline) using git, but may be good for other scenarios as well.

See example in help page:

> You can use a basis based on time:
>
> `$ git bundle create mybundle --since=10.days master`